# Swagger multiple version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Hopefully somebody has tried something similar and provide some guide for me.
I am trying to create multiple versions of Web API. I add below attribute at my controller, so on swagger screen I can see the select definition dropdown to select v1 or v2. Method A will appear on v1, method B will show on v2.

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]
public IActionResult MethodA(Guid id)

[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]
public IActionResult MethodB(Guid id)
```

My question, is it possible to have Method B show on both v1 and v2 ?

I am using below nuget packages on NET6.

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
Unchase.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Extensions
```

Update :
Managed to found a solution. Refer below.

https://developpaper.com/the-grouping-of-net-core-swagger-enables-the-same-action-to-be-shared-by-multiple-groups-and-loads-the-ungrouped-data-at-the-same-time/

Comment: did you tried removing Groupname from Method B. as you want this to appear in both the document ?

Comment: Can  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72554277/15581227) do any benefit for you?

Comment: Thanks all, i managed to found a similar solutions, i have updated in my question