# How to configure versioning for swagger with Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I can't find this method `AddVersionedApiExplorer` to configure swagger in the dotnet core 6 version of `Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer`. What is the new way to configure swagger with this versioning library?

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541447/swaggergeneratorexception-conflicting-method-path-combination-post-api-vversi/72554277#72554277) help you? The `builder.Services.AddApiVersioning` is from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`

Comment: I am looking at this blog post https://moethorstensen.no/versioning-apis/ where they say what about swagger configuration and give an example of configuration for the GroupNameFormatand and SubstituteApiVersionInUrl

Answer (score 6):

Seems that the method has been removed without any indication as to why.

Found this comment in github which seems to be the new way of handling it.

```
        services
            .AddApiVersioning()
            .AddApiExplorer();
```

https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/480#issuecomment-1094107292

Comment: Ok, I looked at that post and I am still left with wondering how to use .AddApiExplorer()  to configure swagger,  assuming that is the method to use now

Comment: @OutOFTouch `Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer` is the replacement package for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer` which was deprecated. It has nothing to do with Swagger and everything to do with API Versioning for the application itself. If you want to implement Swagger, you need to use Swashbuckle or some other package for Swagger configurations.